# jQuery fadein in a particular order

Tags: jquery, fadein

I have jQuery code that is fading images in one by one inside multiple accordion blades.  Every time I click on a new blade, a new set of images begins to fade in one by one, from left to right. However, clicking quickly through the buttons creates a bug as the images start to appear in clumps instead of appearing from let to right. The plugin is at http://preview.hyc.com/hy/process/process.html. How do I get it so that every time I click on a new tab, the new set of fade-in images is reset so that it begins fading in from left to right sequentially?

And the jQuery code I'm using is:

```
$(document).ready(function(i) {
    $(".box").hide();
    var currentBox = $(".container :first-child");
    fadeMyBoxes(currentBox);

    function fadeMyBoxes(thisbox){
        thisbox.fadeIn(2000);
        if (thisbox.is(":last-child")){
            clearTimeout(t);
        }
        else {
            var t =setTimeout( function(){fadeMyBoxes(thisbox.next());},500);
        }
    };

    $("#thetabs ul li").mouseup(function(i) {
        $(".box").hide();
        var currentBox = $(".container :first-child");
        fadeMyBoxes(currentBox);
        function fadeMyBoxes(thisbox){
            thisbox.fadeIn(2000);
            if (thisbox.is(":last-child")){
                clearTimeout(t);
            }
            else {
                var t =setTimeout( function(){fadeMyBoxes(thisbox.next());},500);
            }
        };
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer may lie in chaining rather than using timeouts.  jQuery animation has functions off of it that are executed upon completion of the animation.

```
function fadeChain(elem) {
    if(elem) {
        $(elem).fadeIn('slow', function() {
            fadeChain($(this).next());
        });
    }
}
fadeChain($('#image1'));
```

The proof is in the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/EcaYt/

Comment: Thanks.  I put in that script, and it looks like the first image shows up correctly, but the others still clump together.  The new code is  at: http://preview.hyc.com/hy/process/scripts/fadein.js and http://preview.hyc.com/hy/process/process.html.

Comment: I did a view->source on your page, looked at the JS and I still see references to fadeMyBoxes, and that's the function that you're still calling.  I'd strip out that whole timeout thing.