# Can't use fade and loop in jQuery

Tags: jquery, facebook

I'm trying to load images in and fade one after another using jQuery. The problem is that it only loads one image. How can I fix this problem?

```
$('input[id*="friend_bar"]').click(function () {
    FB.ui({
        method: 'apprequests',
        message: 'Try this awesome application?',
        exclude_ids: '<?php echo $exclude_ids ?>'
    }, function (response) {
        if (response) {
            $.post('invite_suck.php', {
                'response': response.to
            }, function (data) {
                for (var index in response.to) {
                    var ID = response.to[index];
                    $("#friend_bar").first().fadeOut(function () {
                        $(this).load(function () {
                            $(this).fadeIn();
                        });
                        $(this).replaceWith('<div align=\"center\"> <input type=\"image\" src=\"https://graph.facebook.com/' + ID + '/picture/?type=square\" height=\"50\" width=\"50\" align=\"center\">').attr("id", "friend");
                    });
                }
            });
        } 
        else {
            alert('Request was not sent');
        }
    });
```

Comment: Why is this question tagged with [tag:facebook]?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I quite understand your question, but if you're trying to fade in a bunch of images that are contained within a div with the id "friend_bar", you could probably do something like this:

```
//set images opacity at 0
 $('#friend_bar > img').css('opacity', '0');
    //self-invoking function to fade in each image in succession 
 $(function fader() {
     var $image = $('#friend_bar > img');

    $image.each(function(index, item) {
         setTimeout(function() {
             $(item).animate({opacity:1}, 500);
         }, index*500);
     });

 });
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a similar question with regards to fading in some input elements. [jQuery fadein in a particular order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5599739/jquery-fadein-particular-order)

http://jsfiddle.net/lucuma/CVMSx/1/

```
function fadeChain(elem) {
    if(elem) {
        $(elem).fadeIn('slow', function() {
            fadeChain($(this).next());
        });
    }
}

fadeChain($('#slideshow img').first());​
```